# Cannot click on intranet links in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer

I cannot click links to our intranet pages with IE8+Windows 7 Pro (one ASP.NET site that is on the box itself and another on a server on the local network). Nothing happens, JavaScript console shows nothing. I'm at the end of my rope, what can I do to investigate the problem and eventually fix it?

IE shows that I'm in the 'local intranet' zone. I can click links on other sites.

Edit: I've tried and succeeded in clicking links in plain html file. Could there something wrong with the asp.net runtime?

Comment: Can other client PCs on the network open links from the Intranet?  If so I'd suggest the server is serving the pages properly.  

Can you open asp links on internet sites?

Comment: Yes, this issue is localized to one computer only. I've temporarily solved this by installing Firefox and persuading customer to use it instead of IE.